# Jquery how do I validate input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked here and there are plenty of examples out there I am following this example: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mapb_1990/hTPY7/7/) but for me the validation is not working. Can someone suggest me what I am doing wrong. In my homepage if I click on a add button it will show me a bootstrap modal like this:

```
   $(document).on("click", ".homepageAdd", function () {
              $('#modal-dialog').modal("show");
          });
```

After clicking Add button his modal will appear, which contains 3 input fields.

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header btn-add">
            <h4 class="modal-title " id="myModalLabel">Add</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="validation">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>Name:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input class="form-control ref" type="text" required name="name" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>SName:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input class="form-control address" type="text" required name="sname" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>Address:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input class="form-control postcode" type="text" required name="address" /><br />
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary AddButton">Add</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my Jquery I am validating the fields like this: but when i click Add button nothing happens?

```
  $('.AddButton').click(function () {
        $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true
                },
                sname: {
                    required: true
                }

            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
      });
```

Other validation method would be fine.

Comment: there are no elements with a class of `homepageAdd` and how do you click your `AddButton` when it is `display:none`?

Comment: @Pete homepageAdd is a button that is located in my homepage (that works fine) when you click that `class="modal-dialog"` will appear. AND `display:none` was a mistake I've edited.

Comment: What happens when you try validating from the console? you may need to change your function call to `$(document).on('click', '.AddButton', function(){...});` Also, check for typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think this is the problem:

$('#modal-dialog').modal("show"); modal-dialog is not an ID but a class, try the following code and hopefully this time it would work:

The Modal Code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header btn-add">
            <h4 class="modal-title " id="myModalLabel">Add</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="validation">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>Name:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input class="form-control ref" type="text" required name="name" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>SName:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input class="form-control address" type="text" required name="sname" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>Address:</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input class="form-control postcode" type="text" required name="address" /><br />
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary AddButton">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            sname: {
                required: true
            }

        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });

    // You need to add the following event handler to the ".AddButton" button

    $('.AddButton').click(function () {
        $('form').submit();
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".homepageAdd", function () {
        $('#mymodal').modal("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: I know what you're try to do here but when i click on plus button it refreshes the page. I did include `            $('#modal-dialog').modal("show");`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Did you change the modal HTML to have it under 
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
...
</div>
</div>
??
Also, did you try changing the click function to have 
  $('#mymodal').modal("show");
instead of 
  $('#modal-dialog').modal("show");
?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're instantiating the `validate` plugin after the form has been `submit`. It should be done on load of the modal, like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".homepageAdd", function () {
    $('#modal-dialog')
        .on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $('form').validate({
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    sname: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                highlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                },
                unhighlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                },
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorClass: 'help-block',
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                }
            });
        })
   .modal("show");
});
```

The `submit` event of the form will then be stopped if validation fails, or allowed to proceed if the form is valid according to the rules you have provided.

Comment: This is what i thought as well, however I have copied this and placed under document ready(when page load) it still does not work. I have tried placing your code under `$(document).on("click", ".homepageAdd", function () {` because this is where the modal loads- but it still not working.

Comment: @user3812613 I just saw you're doing this in a modal window. Assuming the HTML of the modal is loaded dynamically, you need to create the `validate` in the `show` callback of the modal - assuming it has one.

Comment: Okkk Is there any way you can give me a small example or direct me to some link?

Comment: @user3812613 which modal plugin are you using?

Comment: No, what plugin is giving you the `.modal()` method?

Comment: I am using twitter bootstrap.